# Android tablet orientation can't change

Tags: android, orientation

I'm creating an Android tablet app.

After creating some screen layouts and running the app, the simulator changed from landscape to portrait or visa versa, but the orientation didn't change.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you fixed you orientation in the code or in the manifest???

Comment: If you declare android:screenOrientation="portrait" or "landscape" in android manifest file then please remove that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe two things are possible:

1. Have you fixed your orientation code in the manifest file?
2. Your tab orientation is locked so first open the tab orientation lock...

Comment: what is the meaning of your tab orientation locked so first open the tab orientation lock..? pleaze tell me